# java.lang.OutMemoryError:Failed to allocate

Tags: android

Ошибка вроде известная , но точных и понятных статей на русском нет.Так вот, стали приходить от пользователей ошибки с таким логом.Понимаю , что не хватает памяти, т.к. приложение набито картинками, но как решить , не могу додуматься

вот лог

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=47943KB, Allocated=32855KB)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:626)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:473)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1963)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:670)
    at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:727)
    at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:365)
    at ru.olal.PFCCSKA.PageFragment.onCreateView(PageFragment.java:40)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:490)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1105)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:951)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:250)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:768)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:585)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

вот исходный код

```
private Drawer.Result drawerResult = null;
ViewPager pager;
PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
private int[] images = new int[] {R.drawable.p1,R.drawable.p2,R.drawable.p3,
        R.drawable.p4,R.drawable.p5,R.drawable.p6,R.drawable.p7,R.drawable.p8,
        R.drawable.p9,R.drawable.p11,R.drawable.p12,
        R.drawable.p13,R.drawable.p14,R.drawable.p15,R.drawable.p16,

        R.drawable.p20,R.drawable.p21,R.drawable.p22,
        R.drawable.p23, R.drawable.p24, R.drawable.p25,
        R.drawable.p26, R.drawable.p27,
        R.drawable.p28, R.drawable.p29, R.drawable.p30,
        R.drawable.p40,
        R.drawable.p41, R.drawable.p42, R.drawable.p43,
        R.drawable.p44, R.drawable.p45, R.drawable.p46,
        R.drawable.p47, R.drawable.p49, R.drawable.p50,
        R.drawable.p51,    R.drawable.p52,    R.drawable.p53,
        R.drawable.p55,    R.drawable.p56,    R.drawable.p57,
        R.drawable.p58,    R.drawable.p59,    R.drawable.p60,
        R.drawable.p61,R.drawable.p62,R.drawable.p63,
        R.drawable.p64,R.drawable.p65,R.drawable.p66,
        R.drawable.p67,R.drawable.p68,
        R.drawable.p70, R.drawable.p71, R.drawable.p72,
        R.drawable.p73, R.drawable.p74, R.drawable.p75,
        R.drawable.p76, R.drawable.p77, R.drawable.p78,
        R.drawable.p79, R.drawable.p80,R.drawable.p81,
        R.drawable.p82,R.drawable.p83,R.drawable.p84,
        R.drawable.p85,

};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    adBanner = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adBanner);

            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater adbInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View eulaLayout = adbInflater.inflate(R.layout.checkbox, null);
    dontShowAgain = (CheckBox) eulaLayout.findViewById(R.id.skip);
    adb.setView(eulaLayout);
    adb.setTitle(getString(R.string.title));
    adb.setMessage(getString(R.string.message));
    adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String checkBoxResult = "NOT checked";
            if (dontShowAgain.isChecked())
                checkBoxResult = "checked";
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("skipMessage", checkBoxResult);
            editor.commit();

            return;
        }
    });

    adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String checkBoxResult = "NOT checked";
            if (dontShowAgain.isChecked())
                checkBoxResult = "checked";
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("skipMessage", checkBoxResult);
            editor.commit();

            return;
        }
    });
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    String skipMessage = settings.getString("skipMessage", "NOT checked");
    if (!skipMessage.equals("checked"))
        adb.show();

    super.onResume();


    Button setWlpBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setWlpBtn);
    setWlpBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        private CharSequence text;


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            WallpaperManager wallpaperManager =
                    WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {

                wallpaperManager.setResource(images[pager.getCurrentItem()]);


                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text= ":)";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

    });


    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

        }
    });

    // Инициализируем Navigation Drawer
    drawerResult = new Drawer()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withToolbar(toolbar)
            .withActionBarDrawerToggle(true)
            .withHeader(R.layout.drawer_header)
            .addDrawerItems(

                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.wall).withIdentifier(20),
                    new SectionDrawerItem().withName(R.string.manager),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.lvs).withIdentifier(19),

                    new SectionDrawerItem().withName(R.string.players),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.akinf).withIdentifier(6),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.berez).withIdentifier(7),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.igna).withIdentifier(8),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.mario).withIdentifier(9),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.geogrs).withIdentifier(10),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.nabab).withIdentifier(11),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.wernb).withIdentifier(12),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.natcho).withIdentifier(13),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.dzaga).withIdentifier(14),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.zoran).withIdentifier(15),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.erema).withIdentifier(16),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.musa).withIdentifier(17),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.dumbia).withIdentifier(18),

                    new SectionDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_settings),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_free_play).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_gamepad).withIdentifier(2),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_home).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_home).withIdentifier(1),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_custom).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_eye).withIdentifier(3),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_twitter).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_twitter).withIdentifier(4),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_vk).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_vk).withIdentifier(5),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.about).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_eye).withIdentifier(21)


            )
            .withOnDrawerListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

                    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(MainActivity.this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                }
            })
            .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                // Обработка клика
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                    if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 1) {
                        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3+%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2"));
                        startActivity(browserIntent);

                    }
                    if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 2) {
                        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.olal.PFCCSKA"));
                        startActivity(browserIntent);
                    }
                    if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 3) {
                        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://olalapps.blogspot.ru"));
                        startActivity(browserIntent);
                    }
                    if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 4) {
                        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://twitter.com/olalRadio?s=09"));
                        startActivity(browserIntent);
                    }


                    if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 5) {
                        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://vk.com/id159905319"));
                        startActivity(browserIntent);
                    }
                    if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 6) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent SecAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Akinfa.class);
                        startActivity(SecAct);
                    }
                    if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 7) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent SecAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Berez.class);
                        startActivity(SecAct);
                    }
                    if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 8) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent SecAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Igna.class);
                        startActivity(SecAct);
                    }
                    if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 9) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent SecAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Mario.class);
                        startActivity(SecAct);
                    }
                    if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 10) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent SecAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Goerg.class);
                        startActivity(SecAct);
                    }
                    if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 11) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent SecAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Nabab.class);
                        startActivity(SecAct);
                    }
                    if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 12) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent SecAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Wernb.class);
                        startActivity(SecAct);
                    }
                    if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 13) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent SecAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Natcho.class);
                        startActivity(SecAct);
                    }
                    if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 14) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent SecAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Dzaga.class);
                        startActivity(SecAct);
                    }
                    if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 15) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent SecAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Zoran.class);
                        startActivity(SecAct);
                    }
                    if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 16) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent SecAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Erema.class);
                        startActivity(SecAct);
                    }
                    if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 17) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent SecAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Musa.class);
                        startActivity(SecAct);
                    }
                    if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 18) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent SecAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Dumbia.class);
                        startActivity(SecAct);
                    }

                    if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 19) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent SecAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LVS.class);
                        startActivity(SecAct);
                    }

                    if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 20) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent SecAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(SecAct);
                    }
                    if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 21) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent SecAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), About.class);
                        startActivity(SecAct);
                    }


                }
            })
            .withOnDrawerItemLongClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                // Обработка длинного клика, например, только для SecondaryDrawerItem
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                    if (drawerItem instanceof SecondaryDrawerItem) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this.getString(((SecondaryDrawerItem) drawerItem).getNameRes()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Закрываем Navigation Drawer по нажатию системной кнопки "Назад" если он открыт
    if (drawerResult.isDrawerOpen()) {
        drawerResult.closeDrawer();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

// Заглушка, работа с меню
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

// Заглушка, работа с меню
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    adBanner.loadAd(YOUR_ADLAB_BLOCK_ID);
}



@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    adBanner.pause();
}
private class MyFragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private int[] images = new int[] {R.drawable.p1,R.drawable.p2,R.drawable.p3,
            R.drawable.p4,R.drawable.p5,R.drawable.p6,R.drawable.p7,R.drawable.p8,
            R.drawable.p9,R.drawable.p11,R.drawable.p12,
            R.drawable.p13,R.drawable.p14,R.drawable.p15,R.drawable.p16,

            R.drawable.p20,R.drawable.p21,R.drawable.p22,
            R.drawable.p23, R.drawable.p24, R.drawable.p25,
            R.drawable.p26, R.drawable.p27,
            R.drawable.p28, R.drawable.p29, R.drawable.p30,
            R.drawable.p40,
            R.drawable.p41, R.drawable.p42, R.drawable.p43,
            R.drawable.p44, R.drawable.p45, R.drawable.p46,
            R.drawable.p47, R.drawable.p49, R.drawable.p50,
            R.drawable.p51,    R.drawable.p52,    R.drawable.p53,
            R.drawable.p55,    R.drawable.p56,    R.drawable.p57,
            R.drawable.p58,    R.drawable.p59,    R.drawable.p60,
            R.drawable.p61,R.drawable.p62,R.drawable.p63,
            R.drawable.p64,R.drawable.p65,R.drawable.p66,
            R.drawable.p67,R.drawable.p68,
            R.drawable.p70, R.drawable.p71, R.drawable.p72,
            R.drawable.p73, R.drawable.p74, R.drawable.p75,
            R.drawable.p76, R.drawable.p77, R.drawable.p78,
            R.drawable.p79, R.drawable.p80,R.drawable.p81,
            R.drawable.p82,R.drawable.p83,R.drawable.p84,
            R.drawable.p85,
             };

    private int imagesCount = images.length;

    public MyFragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return PageFragment.newInstance(images[i]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imagesCount;
    }

}
```

}

все остальные активити строятся по такому же скелету , заменяются только id картинок

Comment: Да никак ты ее особо не решишь, не хватает памяти приложению и падает. Либо уменьшай размеры картинок либо используй openGL и загружай картинки в память видеоадаптера, а не держи в оперативке приложения.
 С openGL конечно разбираться долговато, попробуй поискать может какие-то есть фреймфорки не игровые. В теории то конечно можно даже libgdx прицепить.

Comment: Размер картинок и так уменьшал, т.к. некоторые вообще не грузились.Странно то, что на устройствах с 3г оперативы приложение вылетает , а с 2 работает как часы

Comment: largeHeap в манифесте прописан?

Comment: нет.Как и где его прописать?

Comment: да вроде как никаких мега требовательных операций нет, значит `течет` память у Вас...даже если повысите уровень `heap`а снизите количество ошибок, но проблема останется

Comment: и что делать в этом случае?

Answer (score 1):

В манифесте пропишите `largeHeap`:

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        ...
</application>
```

Comment: ко всем активити?

Comment: только `application`

Comment: ну вроде перестало валиться.Не будет проблем с устройствами у которых мало оперативы?

Comment: конкретно от этого флага нет.